# Navigation links in a region rendering vertically

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying to place a block, that contains a navigation menu, within the Navigation region of a Bootstrap themed Drupal 7 site.

The menu is drawn vertically, I assume from the fact that it's a block within the region, and it's overwriting some of the CSS..

It also seems that the UL that is generated for the menu doesn't have the necessary "nav navbar-nav" classes.

Is my only option to override the region.tpl.php, block.tpl.php and the definition for UL (which I have yet to find)?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you want it horiizontally?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the responsible template file from bootstrap theme and put it in sub theme. I think you will find your template under Menu folder in tempaltes of bootstrap theme (parent theme)
You will find these files and you have to modify one of these in order to achieve what you said.

1. menu-link.func.php
2. menu-local-action.func.php
3. menu-local-task.func.php
4. menu-local-tasks.func.php
5. menu-tree.func.php

Thanks